# Is where way to mock image which comes from API with $httpBackend of angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, httpbackend

i'm doing protractor tests and using angular-mocks to "fake" requests.
In my app where is one place where image should be displayed:

```
<img ng-src="api/documents/image/{{file.Id}}">
```

Is it possible to intrcept the request for getting image data and replace it by some fake image data, in the way things done with json?

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('api/documents/123').respond(200,[]);
```

Currently i'm getting broken image icons on the screen, which i prefer to be replaced by some fake images.
I hope that it is possible...

Kind regards

Comment: You should give [`protractor-http-mock`](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock) a try.

Comment: Thanks , but i cannot see any examples of mocking image data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) just accepts an expression/static path - it doesn't perform an `$http` call which you can mock unless your expression is a function call to fetch images which is probably not what you want. I would recommend:

1) Add a config variable to your image paths that can be switched for dev/prod such as:

```
 ng-src="{{ baseUrl }}/api/documents/image/{{file.Id}}"
```

2) Point this `baseUrl` to a dev server which delivers whatever mock images you desire. You can create a simple Express server that delivers the same image for every request for example.

Comment: you are genius. Also found "grunt-express-server" task which can start the mock server before protractor starting to run